# How to get list of entries in properties file using Apache commons config?

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

In my project we have a properties file which has some entries as below:

```
#Data key entries
datakey001
datakey321
datakey451
someotherkey
```

In fact its not a key value pair, but a list of keys. Using `java.util.Properties` I was able to get this using `Properties.stringPropertyNames()`.

Now we are migrating to Apache Commons Configuration and I could not find any feature in this library to get all these keys as I used to get previously using `java.util.Properties`.

Is there any way in apache commons config by which I can get all these keys without changing the the structure of the properties file?

EDIT: I have tried using `Configuration.getKeys()` as below, but the output is empty.

```
 Configuration propertiesConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration("C:\\proj\\myprops.properties");
 Iterator<String> it = propertiesConfig.getKeys();
 while(it.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(it.next());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Configuration.getKeys()` [method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration.html#getKeys%28%29) for that.

Comment: Thanks Gergely! but that's something I had tried and I forgot to mention in the question. When I use Configuration.getKeys(), I get an empty iterator in this case. WIll update the question now.

Comment: That is strange. Just for testing purposes, could you add a few "=" signs to the end of your rows to see if that does the trick? Maybe your valueless config entries are treated as malformatted inputs.

Comment: Yeah, when I add "=" sign I am able to fetch the keys. Looks like the entries are treated as malformatted inputs. Any ideas/workarounds that I can try at the code level?

Comment: No idea what to do on code level. Honestly I would just add those "=" signs everywhere. It is a one-minute-job on linux: sed 's/$/=/g' myprops.properties , or in any fancy Windows text-editor.